# Rewrite URL for Payment Gateway

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, woocommerce

I am working on a payment gateway that doesn't allow "?" in Callback URLs. This payment gateway has to be integrated with Wordpress + Woocommerce.

My callback URL seems to be

```
http://localhost/payment/index.php/my-account/?wc-api=WC_Gateway_Abc
```

I want to use it in a different way so payment gateway doesn't give an error. Here is an example:

```
http://localhost/payment/index.php/my-account/wc-api/WC_Gateway_Abc
```

and later, I want to rewrite it using htaccess when payment gateway sends back response to Wordpress site so Wordpress file can execute the response.

Apparently, only

> ?wc-api=WC_Gateway_Abc

part should be re-writable.

**P.S: This is a plugin so I can't change Wordpress files outside my Plugin directory.**

Any hints for htaccess rewrite condition?

Comment: you can set rewrite tag and then add and set rewrite rule for custom URL in to init hook and after flush permalink you can see effect as well for particular page.https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule

Comment: @AshPatel This is a plugin so I can't edit files outside of my plugin directory.

Comment: yes but you can try/check in plugin function file or add into theme function file for add rewrite URL for particular query string of payment gateway.

Answer (score 0):

that would be an possible option

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)\/wc-api\/(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1?wc-api=%2 [L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```